# Checking Status Code in Angular 5

Tags: angular, http-post, angular5, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using .NET Core 2.1 API in my Angular APP

Below is my API

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
    public ObjectResult CheckLogIn([FromBody] LogIn model)
    {
        try
        {
            UserInfo user = new UserInfo();
            using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(configuration.GetConnectionString("constr")))
            {
                user = db.Query<UserInfo>("SP_Loginportal",
                    new
                    {
                        UserId = model.EmployeeCode,
                        Password = util.EncryptMD5(model.Password)
                    }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).FirstOrDefault();
            }
            if (user != null)
            {
                return StatusCode(200, user);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(401, new ResultSet() { Message = "Invalid Credential or Unauthorized", StatusCode = 401 });
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException sx)
        {
            return StatusCode(503, new ResultSet() { Message = "Service is Currently Unavailable", StatusCode = 503 });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500, new ResultSet() { Message = ex.Message, StatusCode = 500 });
        }
        finally
        {
        }
        return StatusCode(404, new UserInfo());
    }
```

And in angular

```
LogIn() {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
};
var payload = JSON.stringify(this.login);
var url = this.baseURL + 'api/LogIn/CheckLogIn/';
this.http.post<UserInfo>(url, payload, httpOptions)
  .subscribe(result => {
    if (result != null) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("UserID", result.StaffCode);
      sessionStorage.setItem("UserName", result.StaffName);
      sessionStorage.setItem("UserRole", result.StaffRole);
      sessionStorage.setItem("BrancName", result.BranchName);
      sessionStorage.setItem("BranchCode", result.BranchCode);
      this.router.navigate(['/indusindform'])
    }
    else {
      this.ErrorMessage = "Invalid";
    }
  }, error => console.error(error))
```

}

In http.post call , inside subscribe block I want to check whether API Status Code is 200 or 401 , 503 or 500 , than on basis of that I want to display message which I am returning in ResultSet.

How can I check API status Code before Using its data ?

Comment: https://angular.io/api/http/Response

Comment: @AmitChigadani How to use it with http calls ?

Comment: Just print the response, you will see all those attributes. You should also add `observe: 'response'` to your `httpOptions` parameter as shown by the answer below.

Comment: @AmitChigadani , after adding observe: 'response' it give error - the type of property observe is incompatible

Comment: and Print what response ?? have to declare any variable ?

Answer (score 2):

In the httpOptions use this:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  observe: 'response'  // add this line
};
```

Comment: how to use it within http calls ?

Comment: After adding this your data will be within result.data.

Comment: don't forget that I am casting result to my class so it only suggest property name , not status code or other properties